# Is gtk+ responsible for the awkward look of most linux applications?

Tags: linux, gtk, gnome

Now, I know this is completely subjective, so please don't flame me. I've never been entirely satisfied with linux whenever I decided to install a distro like Ubuntu, Fedora etc. because of their awkward positioning and spacing of widgets.

Have a look at [this](http://art.gnome.org/themes/gtk2/?sort_by=popularity&limit=12&view=list&order=DESC):

[image]

[image]

Notice the awkward spacing of the text field's text.

I've seen many Gnome themes that look good on the surface but it all somehow breaks down, awkward spacings, strange borders. Etc.

The entire linux desktop doesn't have the visual integrity of OSX for instance, and I wonder why. If there is any example of a nice integrated Linux environment, please please please show me, I really WANT to use Linux.

(and I know, there's QT, and other managers like KDE etc. I noticed the same thing, so it probably isn't GTK or Gnome alone)

Comment: I think the question should be rephrased as, "What goes into making an aesthetically appealing desktop UI?" or something, that asks much of the same thing about pushing on people's buttons. I can imagine some disgruntled person closing this post out of spite. :-P

Comment: Well... the thing is, I just want to know how I can improve the my perception... I work in an ad agency and a lot of the graphic designers point out that linux feels awkward to them because of the spacing of controls, violating basic grid rules etc.

Comment: I must not have a graphic designer's eye. What's awkward about the text? Too close to the edge of the rounded rectangle? The other one looks perfectly fine to me.

Comment: Ryan: on the second image, the "Button" text is sliced of (it says "butto").

Comment: You are aware that that's only a preview image and not a real button used in a real program right ?

Comment: dbr: What would you recommend be done if a button is sized too small for its text? Keep in mind that the programmer must *explicitly* size the button too small -- by default, it will display correctly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The entire linux desktop doesn't have the visual integrity of OSX for instance, and I wonder why. If there is any example of a nice integrated Linux environment, please please please show me, I really WANT to use Linux.
>
> (and I know, there's QT, and other managers like KDE etc. I noticed the same thing, so it probably isn't GTK or Gnome alone)

You basically just answered your own question - Mac OS X has **one** desktop environment (centered around Cocoa), which has a lot of very good programmers *and* designers spending much time designing, discussing and implementing it.

With "Linux", there's not only different window managers (Gnome, KDE, Flux/OpenBox, Enlightenment, etc etc), there's different UI toolkits (QT, GTK+, Tk, wx, etc etc), different versions (in common use), and countless different ways of using/implementing them.. Compare [List of (mainly) Linux GUI toolkits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_widget_toolkits#Based_on_C_or_C.2B.2B_.28including_bindings_to_other_languages.2) compared to for [Macintosh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_widget_toolkits#On_Macintosh) (all of those, bar Cocoa, are for old Mac OS versions).

There's many good designers and programmers working on GUI toolkits, but they are spread over so many different projects. Even if they somehow were put onto a single project (Say, "wxQtGnome"), there would still be countless applications that use a different framework, or even a different version of one.. Then you still have the problem with inconsistency. Again, compared to Mac OS X, where if you have a GUI application, chances are it will be using Cocoa (which has a decent UI creation tool, which helps developers layout applications according to Apples Human UI Guidelines)..

As for a nice, integrated linux desktop environment - I would say the default Ubuntu installation is probably the closest to this. A decent theme, and all the applications fit fairly well together.

Comment: There is no "GTK". Perhaps you're thinking of GTK+ 1.x and GTK+ 2.x.

Answer (score 11):

I would say it has to do with then open source movement attracting more coders then artists. Also remember that Apple spends a lot of money on their user interface and they still take [criticism](http://www.indiehig.com/blog/2007/09/09/fix-the-leopard-folders/).

Answer (score 4):

The quality of the themes also vary.. It shouldn't be that hard to find a theme that's "horribly wrong" because of its basic choices and priorities. Personally, I like very compressed themes. I even used the [Enlightenment](http://enlightenment.org) window manager, known for it's eye-candy, to get rid of window decorations completely. So I might choose a violently cramped theme and be very happy, despite the odd glitches that make you wig out.

I'd instead say that Gtk/Gnome is really the reason you are looking at a GNU/Linux desktop *at all*. The stuff that went before it was [*truly* heinous](http://www.catb.org/~esr/writings/taouu/html/ch02s06.html#OpenLook) *all the time!* (No offence to the creators of XAW, but they probably didn't have "lickable" as a goal...)

Comment: Also, that screenshot shows Motif widgets, not Xaw, Xaw looked even worse ;)

Comment: Yeah. I was a bit a bit confused... (Some things I prefer not to remember I guess...) Do you have a screenshot of that Xaw?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using KDE with one of default themes (Plastic) and I'm yet to see anything awkward there.

I also use Gtk2 applications and still haven't seen anything awkward there. You should know that using any theme that is not *officially* supported by Gnome/KDE can have bugs.

However, all this can be very subjective. For example, I find **some** of Windows XP UI to be awkward and/or just plain ugly. Different people have different tastes and habits. Maybe it's because I used Windows98, then Linux, then Windows XP, so everything is awkward. And you are probably coming from the other direction.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is twofold:

1. Everyone seems to use the UI toolkit of their choice, which leads to a horrid mismatch of apps.
2. UI designers cost good money, so most UI work in Linux is amatuer, and it shows.

Additionally, theming is evil and should never have been implemented. But thats just my IHMO, it totally ruins consistency.

Comment: I don't mind the whole system theming in Gtk - I can't really see the point, but it seems harmless. I really hate applications that have their own skinning. Normally one of the skins is a poor attempt at looking like what the OS would do if they hadn't gone to all that trouble!

Answer (score 1):

You know, it's just a different approach. The differences between particular themes are inevitable, as there isn't any sort of common guidelines, AFAIK.

For me, Linux themes are completely integral, I've yet to experience any sort of feeling of awkwardness.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the OSX-like theme has unaligned text placement but most of the others on the page you linked looks fine to me?

Also, It's not too hard to fix those things. As @nemo stated, there are "way" more coders than artists in free software world. If you make suggestions as an artist to a theme maker, they will probably be incorporated in the next release. That's how  free and open source software world works.

Answer (score 1):

As for the example picture, maybe you could post similar pictures for GUIs that you do like (Mac OS, Window...)? That might make it easier to compare the GUIs and see subtle differences.

Anyway, I think the preview images on art.gnome.org are not representative for the real look. If you want to compare GTK+ GUIs with other toolkits, I suggest to look at screenshots from real apps. For example, Ubuntu with default theme should be quite representative.

Btw. the Gnome HIG (Human Interface Guidelines) have a chapter on layout and spacing: http://library.gnome.org/devel/hig-book/stable/design-window.html.en .

Answer (score 1):

I don't think GTK+ itself is responsible for the "awkward look" (which is your subjective opinion!) of Linux applications.

In fact, GTK+ is *very* flexible with regards to the possibility to apply themes and even completely different rendering engines for the widgets (see the popular [Murrine](http://www.cimitan.com/murrine/) engine for example). It's much more flexible than the native GUI libraries of Windows and Mac OS X.

You can find lots of GNOME themes on for example [gnome-look.org](http://www.gnome-look.org/). There are even GNOME themes that make your GNOME desktop look almost exactly like Windows Vista or Mac OS X (I don't understand why anyone would want that, but that's a personal thing...).

Canonical, the company behind Ubuntu, has been saying for some time that they're hiring professional designers to create a very sleek and professionally designed desktop theme for some future version of Ubuntu.